# Kotlin + Java 10 + Maven + Java Modules == fail

Tags: maven, kotlin, java-9, java-module, java-10

I have a project using Java 10 (also works with Java 9) using kotlin 1.2.31, and the kotlin-maven-plugin

When I start adding module-info.java files to my projects, then the kotlin compiler fails with the stack trace below.

I've tried all the under-development version of the kotlin-maven-compiler, but no luck.

It looks like the compiler is using a re-packaged/shaded version of objectweb asm... however I'm unable to find the source for this to see what is happening at ClassReader.java:2659

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.2.31:compile (compile) on project athena_event: Compilation failure
[ERROR] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readStringish(ClassReader.java:2659)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:2693)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readModule(ClassReader.java:726)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:632)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.modules.JavaModuleInfo$Companion.read(JavaModuleInfo.kt:67)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.modularBinaryRoot(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:164)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.computeRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:118)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.ClasspathRootsResolver.convertClasspathRoots(ClasspathRootsResolver.kt:79)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:233)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment.<init>(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:117)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinCoreEnvironment$Companion.createForProduction(KotlinCoreEnvironment.kt:413)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.createCoreEnvironment(K2JVMCompiler.kt:276)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:195)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:63)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:108)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:52)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execCompiler(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:237)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:233)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execCompiler(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:55)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execute(KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:220)
[ERROR] at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execute(K2JVMCompileMojo.java:218)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: If they have shaded the asm (which needs to be updated for JDK10) parts than you are out of luck. Thats the disadvantage of shaded dependencies. This prevents simple overwriting of dependencies....